# PHP Doctrine truncates string to 65534 characters

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

i was tasked with a project whitch uses Doctrine as ORM. I have almost no experience with this framework.

The issue is that when i set string data into field and flush into DB, string inside DB (MySQL) gets truncated to only 65534 characters. Column in MySQL is set to LONGTEXT and i can manually push larger strings inside this column without any issue. I believe the issue is with Doctrine entity, the problematic field looks like this:

```
    /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="data", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $data;
```

I tried using `columnType="longtext"` but it did not help. Do i need to update doctrine somehow so it "syncs" or what should i try ?

I did check that the data that i pass into this field has correct length and is not truncated.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What doctrine/orm version are you using? I checked on v2.6.3 and by default it creates LONGTEXT field with maximum length possible and it does not truncate anything. Also, it should be `columnDefinition="longtext"` instead of "columnType". You may also try to set "length" parameter to maximum length of LONGTEXT: `length=4294967292`

Comment: Version of doctrine is 2.4.8. I also tried what you suggested and nothing happened.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36583206/693546

Comment: setting lenght or columnDefinition did not help, problem still persists